The OpenStack network uses OVN (Geneve). The geneve internal network port (network: distributed) of the second computing node is in the DOWN state
May I ask where I can find instructions for this port.
All the cloud hosts I created in the second computing node cannot access the internal gateway.
info
|   host   |               IP                       |         disk         | CPU  | memory |
| :--------: | :-----------------------------:      | :------------------: | :--: | :----: |
| controller | NIC1：10.0.0.10，NIC2：192.168.101.10 |      sda：100G       |  2C  |   6G   |
| compute01  | NIC1：10.0.0.11，NIC2：192.168.101.20 | sda：100G ，sdb：20G |  2C  |   4G   |
| compute02  | NIC1：10.0.0.12，NIC2：192.168.101.30 | sda：100G ，sdb：20G |  2C  |   4G   |

Related configurations（controller）
systemctl restart ovn-central ovn-northd
ovn-nbctl set-connection ptcp:6641:10.0.0.10 -- set connection . inactivity_probe=60000
ovn-sbctl set-connection ptcp:6642:10.0.0.10 -- set connection . inactivity_probe=60000

ovs-vsctl add-br br-eth1
ovs-vsctl add-port br-eth1 eth1

ovs-vsctl set open . external-ids:ovn-bridge-mappings=physnet1:br-eth1

Related configurations（compute）
ovs-vsctl set open . external-ids:ovn-remote=tcp:10.0.0.10:6642

ovs-vsctl set open . external-ids:ovn-encap-type=geneve

ovs-vsctl set open . external-ids:ovn-encap-ip=10.0.0.11


ovs-vsctl add-br br-eth1
ovs-vsctl add-port br-eth1 eth1

ovs-vsctl set open . external-ids:ovn-bridge-mappings=physnet1:br-eth1

result
root@controller:~# openstack network agent list
+--------------------------------------+----------------------+----------+-------------------+-------+-------+----------------------------+
| ID                                   | Agent Type           | Host     | Availability Zone | Alive | State | Binary                     |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------+----------+-------------------+-------+-------+----------------------------+
| 0458befc-c211-5427-88cf-67f547145ef7 | OVN Metadata agent   | compute2 |                   | :-)   | UP    | neutron-ovn-metadata-agent |
| ecbac5ab-11be-4d00-a168-bdfceb3e585c | OVN Controller agent | compute2 |                   | :-)   | UP    | ovn-controller             |
| 607ac584-d4db-5de5-a9ea-6ac9ddf9ecb0 | OVN Metadata agent   | compute1 |                   | :-)   | UP    | neutron-ovn-metadata-agent |
| fb6d05b9-dbbd-4b83-9585-fba791e3b69b | OVN Controller agent | compute1 |                   | :-)   | UP    | ovn-controller             |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------+----------+-------------------+-------+-------+----------------------------+

I created 10.0.0.0/24 as Geneve (internal network) and 192.168.101.0/24 as flat (external network) for the cloud host
Router created and functioning properly
This is a port owned by the intranet in the second calculator that is in the DOWN state
root@controller:~# openstack port show b3acd11d-a06f-4f6b-ae77-1300733ee204
+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field                   | Value                                                                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| admin_state_up          | UP                                                                      |
| allowed_address_pairs   |                                                                         |
| binding_host_id         |                                                                         |
| binding_profile         |                                                                         |
| binding_vif_details     |                                                                         |
| binding_vif_type        | unbound                                                                 |
| binding_vnic_type       | normal                                                                  |
| created_at              | 2024-07-14T02:25:41Z                                                    |
| data_plane_status       | None                                                                    |
| description             |                                                                         |
| device_id               | ovnmeta-ae1a9ca9-7f90-4d9e-9773-441a313094e5                            |
| device_owner            | network:distributed                                                     |
| device_profile          | None                                                                    |
| dns_assignment          | None                                                                    |
| dns_domain              | None                                                                    |
| dns_name                | None                                                                    |
| extra_dhcp_opts         |                                                                         |
| fixed_ips               | ip_address='10.0.0.2', subnet_id='908010c2-c716-4bb0-a469-8451648f2cbe' |
| hardware_offload_type   | None                                                                    |
| hints                   |                                                                         |
| id                      | b3acd11d-a06f-4f6b-ae77-1300733ee204                                    |
| ip_allocation           | None                                                                    |
| mac_address             | fa:16:3e:ae:7e:01                                                       |
| name                    |                                                                         |
| network_id              | ae1a9ca9-7f90-4d9e-9773-441a313094e5                                    |
| numa_affinity_policy    | None                                                                    |
| port_security_enabled   | False                                                                   |
| project_id              | 103fa649bacc4dea8e3a8d6e3d10da04                                        |
| propagate_uplink_status | None                                                                    |
| resource_request        | None                                                                    |
| revision_number         | 2                                                                       |
| qos_network_policy_id   | None                                                                    |
| qos_policy_id           | None                                                                    |
| security_group_ids      |                                                                         |
| status                  | DOWN                                                                    |
| tags                    |                                                                         |
| trunk_details           | None                                                                    |
| updated_at              | 2024-07-14T02:25:42Z                                                    |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Not only that, there is also an interface in the second calculator's external network that is in the DOWN state.
root@controller:~# openstack port show  d8b71fe2-adad-40ce-94a6-de75788b5cfe
+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field                   | Value                                                                         |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| admin_state_up          | UP                                                                            |
| allowed_address_pairs   |                                                                               |
| binding_host_id         |                                                                               |
| binding_profile         |                                                                               |
| binding_vif_details     |                                                                               |
| binding_vif_type        | unbound                                                                       |
| binding_vnic_type       | normal                                                                        |
| created_at              | 2024-07-14T02:27:06Z                                                          |
| data_plane_status       | None                                                                          |
| description             |                                                                               |
| device_id               | ovnmeta-2d2f7ba2-6927-48d3-a460-431c543db66b                                  |
| device_owner            | network:distributed                                                           |
| device_profile          | None                                                                          |
| dns_assignment          | None                                                                          |
| dns_domain              | None                                                                          |
| dns_name                | None                                                                          |
| extra_dhcp_opts         |                                                                               |
| fixed_ips               | ip_address='192.168.101.41', subnet_id='caeb8246-bcd6-42f0-94ec-434bcdc2bdc7' |
| hardware_offload_type   | None                                                                          |
| hints                   |                                                                               |
| id                      | d8b71fe2-adad-40ce-94a6-de75788b5cfe                                          |
| ip_allocation           | None                                                                          |
| mac_address             | fa:16:3e:c0:b2:b9                                                             |
| name                    |                                                                               |
| network_id              | 2d2f7ba2-6927-48d3-a460-431c543db66b                                          |
| numa_affinity_policy    | None                                                                          |
| port_security_enabled   | False                                                                         |
| project_id              | 103fa649bacc4dea8e3a8d6e3d10da04                                              |
| propagate_uplink_status | None                                                                          |
| resource_request        | None                                                                          |
| revision_number         | 2                                                                             |
| qos_network_policy_id   | None                                                                          |
| qos_policy_id           | None                                                                          |
| security_group_ids      |                                                                               |
| status                  | DOWN                                                                          |
| tags                    |                                                                               |
| trunk_details           | None                                                                          |
| updated_at              | 2024-07-14T02:27:07Z                                                          |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

I have never known the network: distributed port type
I estimate that I made some mistake in my configuration. If there are any documents, please provide them as well. Thank you.
